# Check if key exists in $_SESSION by building index string

Tags: php, arrays

I need to check if a key exists and return its value if it does.
Key can be an array with subkeys or endkey with a value.

```
$_SESSION['mainKey']['testkey'] = 'value';
var_dump(doesKeyExist('testkey'));
function doesKeyExist($where) {
  $parts = explode('/',$where);
  $str = '';
  for($i = 0,$len = count($parts);$i<$len;$i++) {
    $str .= '[\''. $parts[$i] .'\']';
  }
  $keycheck = '$_SESSION[\'mainKey\']' . $str;
  if (isset(${$keycheck})) {
    return ${$keycheck};
  }

  // isset($keycheck) = true, as its non-empty. actual content is not checked
  // isset(${$keycheck}) = false, but should be true. ${$var} forces a evaluate content
  // isset($_SESSION['mainKey']['testkey']) = true
}
```

Using PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing here. Can you elaborate? Are you checking for values like `mainKey/testkey`?

Comment: @Pekka: I think `doesKeyExist('foo')` should look for _SESSION[mainKey][foo] and `doesKeyExist('foo/bar')` should look for _SESSION[mainKey][foo][bar].

Comment: What does that mean?  ${$var} forces a evaluate content

Comment: @Nabab: It means using the `${$}` notation will look for `${$_SESSION['mainKey']['foo']}` which is obviously not what OP intended.

Comment: @BoltClock: It actually is what I wanted and I used this method in the past, but I forgot to check if it works on SUPERGLOBALS which it does NOT. Christian Joudrey provided an alternative solution (I was being blinded by my.. arrogance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of building the string, just check if the key exists within your loop.

For instance:

```
function doesKeyExist($where) {
  $parts = explode('/',$where);
  $currentPart = $_SESSION['mainKey'];
  foreach($parts as $part) {
    if (!isset($currentPart[$part])) {
      return false;
    }
    $currentPart = $currentPart[$part];
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is much much safer. OP's current code would eventually lead to a use of `eval()`.

Comment: What if `$_SESSION['mainKey']` does not exist?

Comment: Just need to add a verification before starting the loop. I took for granted that it does since OP hardcoded in his function. i.e. `if (!isset($_SESSION['mainKey'])) return false;`

Comment: @Christian Joudrey: But he used `isset(${$keycheck})` that would check that too if that syntax were possible.

Comment: I just tried that out and it doesn't seem to be working. Whether this is a PHP bug or not, I'd rather stick to my solution as it seems cleaner to me. I am copying arrays to memory, but I'm assuming he wouldn't store anything large in the session anyway.

Comment: I was so set on getting ${$var} to work that I didnt consider just using the loop. The link in Gerbens answer shows a warning that ${$var} will not work on SUPERGLOBALS, no wonder I had problems. I have a check $_SESSION['mainKey'] prior to the loop, but I just simplified the problem for SO. Also, a for-loop is faster (not much) than a foreach-loop and since explode() returns a numeric array without gaps did I use that. Finally, eval() is bad. Avoid it!

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! Indeed, a for() loop would be more efficient, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getByKeys($keys, $array) {
  $value = $array;
  foreach (explode('/', $keys) as $key) {
    if (isset($value[$key])) {
      $value = $value[$key];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but this would appear to be the simplest way of doing it:

```
function getKey($arr, $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
        return $arr[$key];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$value = getKey($_SESSION['mainKey'], 'testkey');
```

Comment: He wants something that can search deeper into the array as well. For instance checking if `$_SESSION['mainKey']['testkey']['testkey2']` exists.

Comment: That's where clarity of the original question is important.

Answer (score -1):

You should use $$keycheck, not ${$keycheck}.

The last notation is only if you use the variable inside a string (e.g. "${$keycheck}")

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php for more details about variable variables

Comment: But `$$keycheck` is equivalent to `${$keycheck}`, and `${$keycheck}` is legal syntax outside strings.

Answer (score -4):

You might want to use the **eval()** php function for this.

```
function doesKeyExist($where) {
  $parts = explode('/',$where);
  $str = '';
  for($i = 0,$len = count($parts);$i<$len;$i++) {
    $str .= '["'. $parts[$i] .'"]';
  }
  eval('$keycheck = $_SESSION["mainKey"]' . $str . ';');
  if (isset($keycheck)) {
    return $keycheck;
  }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Ew. This is vulnerable in many more ways than I can think of.

Comment: I agree, but if he sanitizes the input, I think it's safe. Right?